# Why isn't wget accepting my username/password?

Tags: passwords, wget

I've tried both

```
wget --user=myuser --password=mypassword myfile
```

and

```
wget --ftp-user=myuser --ftp-password=mypassword myfile
```

but I keep getting the error

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.
```

I know the file is there, and I know the username/password are correct - I can ftp in with no problem. Any thoughts on what's going on here? How do I even tell if `wget` is paying attention to the username/password that I'm giving it? (The error is the same if I simply don't provide that info.)

Comment: Why do you get an HTTP error when you want to do FTP?

Comment: Well, are you doing it in a script?

Comment: Yes (well, initially just command line to figure it out, but now it's part of a script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using an "ftp://" URL?  From the error message it appears that you're making a request for an "http://" URL.

Answer (score 26):

try wget --http-user=username --http-password=password http://....

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

One more comment:

Setting `--user`  and `--password` sets the user/pw for both ftp and http requests, so that's more general.

In my case, nothing worked, except using `--ask-password`

I was using a https URL.

Answer (score 0):

it might be useful to add that if you need to add a domain name before that the backslash must be escaped i.e. "\" is preceded with another "\" e.g. "domain\\username" similarly if the password has any chars that requires escaping (i supposed, havn't tested it).

```
wget --http-user=domain\\\username --http-password=password http://...
```